# How to pass an ArrayList from one jsp to another using session

Tags: java, jsp, session, arraylist

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList from handle.jsp to main.jsp, but it doesn't let me do it. It keeps saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to ArrayList".

main.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hobby Manager</h1>
<%

        ArrayList<String> hobbies = session.getAttribute("hobbies");

        out.println(hobbies.size());

        out.println(session.getAttribute("hobbies"));
%>

    <h2>Add new hobby!</h2>

    <FORM action="handleAddHobby.jsp" method="get">
            What new hobby are you wishing to add? <INPUT TYPE=text name=hobbyName /> <br/>

            <INPUT TYPE=submit name=addHobby value="Add Hobby" />

    </FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

handle.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<html>
<body>

<%
    ArrayList<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();

    String hobbyName = request.getParameter("hobbyName");

    if(hobbyName == null){
            out.println("Please enter a hobby before clicking add! Dummy.<br/>");
    }   
    else{
            hobbies.add(hobbyName);

            for(int index = 0; index < hobbies.size(); index ++){
                    out.println(hobbies.get(index) + "<br/>");
            }   

            session.setAttribute("hobbies", hobbies);
    }   
%>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried passing it as a string object, and passing it as an object alone but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How are you going from the handle to the main page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is here ..

```
ArrayList<String> hobbies = session.getAttribute("hobbies");
```

Try typecasting it as getAttribute always returns Object.

```
ArrayList<String> hobbies = (ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("hobbies");
```